# Export 'sp_execute_external_script' value to SQL variable for use

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I am trying to write a stored procedure that is using the SQL sp_execute_external_script procedure. I am able to have the script run in my SSMS window. I want to save the value to an OUTPUT variable that I can use later in the stored procedure.

Here is what I have working:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
    ,@script = N'OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(qgamma(p=(.05/2),shape=315,scale=1)); '
```

I am using SQL Server 2019.
I tried this, but the variable does not populate:

```
DECLARE @UpDiv float

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
    ,@script = N'OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(qgamma(p=(.05/2),shape=315,scale=1)); '
    ,@params = N'@UpDiv float OUTPUT'
    ,@UpDiv = @UpDiv OUTPUT

    SELECT @UpDiv
```

Edit: From suggestions, I made a small change to send to UpDiv, but now my issue is with how do I get the "data.frame" result to an SQL variable? What variable do I use? I am having to learn R on the fly here. Can I maybe convert in the R result before passing back to SQL?

Comment: `UpDiv <- something` perhaps? It doesn't look like you are actually setting it anywhere

Comment: Similar to an answer below, which does work, I believe my issue is with the "data.frame" designation. I have edited my original question. I don't know how to get an R data.frame out to the SQL server.

Comment: I'm confused: do you want a single scalar value? Then the answer works. Or do you want a whole table, in which case I think you need `INSERT ... EXEC sp_execute_external_script ... WITH RESULT SETS...` like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-r-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15#use-inputs-and-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

...

```
DECLARE @UpDiv float;

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
    ,@script = N'UpDiv <- sum(1.01, 2.02, 3.03, 4.04, 5.05) '
    ,@params = N'@UpDiv float OUTPUT'
    ,@UpDiv = @UpDiv OUTPUT;

SELECT @UpDiv;
```